# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I am running an SSIS package that uses OLEDB connections to fetch data from and Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 database and insert it into an SQLServer 2012 (11.0.6260)

I get the following error.

```
Time: 2021-02-05 01:13:55 AM
Task: Data Flow Task
Error Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
```

followed by

```
Time: 2021-02-05 01:13:55 AM
Task: Data Flow Task
Error Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

There are no keys or constraints on the destination table.

Both of the dataflow tasks have `CommandTimeout` set to `0`.

All of the other packages with the same source and destination databases run without any problem.

**Edit 2**

This particular package runs fine on our test/development environment.

*I have sinced run the package several times and noticed that the source query returns about 4500 records but only about 500 are inserted into the destination database.*

**End Edit 2**

Is there anything else that I can check for?

**Edit 1**

The Error message is as it appears in service manager.

[image: Error Message]

The log files just before the error are below.

[image]

The source Query is quite along running query. It takes approximately 9 minutes.

**End Edit 1**

Comment: did you try to remove the destination table, add a derived column to the dataflow and enable the data viewer on this flow? Might give an idea on which data is returned from the source query. Anyhow, it might be that you have a data type mismatch between source and destination - not all oracle type can be inserted 1:1 into SQL Server tables

Comment: The error message is cut off at the first line.   Tricky since you can't recreated it in dev.  If you can run it via the ssis catalog and check Reports > All Executions > All Messages, you should get the bottom half of those messages with more details.

Comment: @vhoang. The error is also cut off in 'All Messages'. See Edit 1 above.

Comment: @Tyron78 I'll try adding a derived column. All the columns are either `datetime`, `number` or `nvarchar`, so nothing too complicated there. The source and destination tables are exactly the same in both the production and development environments.

Comment: Since you are sure it's the same dataset while in dev.   Consider setting the package property MaxConcurrentExecutables from -1 to 1.  Similar but not exact [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429106/8408335).

Comment: tried changing `Rows Per Batch` and `Max Insert Commit Size` as described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054086/is-there-any-releavance-for-row-per-batch-and-max-insert-commit-size-in-ssis

Comment: @vhoang I have tried to change the `MaxConcurrentExecutables` but still getting the same result.

Comment: changed `MaximumErrorCount` to `3` I'm now getting some data coming through but still getting the above errors.

Comment: tried setting `Delay Validation` to `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging into the oracle database directly with the user that is used for our integrations and running the query gave the following error.

[image: oracle error ORA-02392]

After increasing the size of the user profile the query returned data and the integrations ran correctly.